# ¿Cómo se agrega una herramienta de un paquete de NuGet al toolbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, microsoft

Estube leyendo la documentación de Microsoft webview2 y en la sección de integración desde NuGet a winforms(c#) dice que debería de agregarse el control webview2 al toolbox automáticamente, como no sucedió, quiero saber si existe una forma manual de agregar este control desde el paquete NuGet al toolbox, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Si no estoy equivocado, los Nuget son librerias unicamente que se agregan a tu proyecto y lo que estas pidiendo es una Extension, que cuando la instalas se agrega a visual studio y la podes usar como herramienta o como haga sido diseñada donde deba aparecer

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de la base que `nuget` no tiene relacion con la `toolbox`.

Si referenciaste en el proyecto alguna libreria que ademas tiene una parte visual podrias buscarla usando el `Choose items` de la propia `toolbox`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces buscas la libreria que quieres agregar

---

Si hiciste referencia a este componente

[Getting started with WebView2 in Windows Forms apps (Preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms)

puede que te lo muestre directamente, pero no es por algo de `nuget` sino porque el propio Visual Studio carga componentes que hayas referenciado, pero previamente debes compilar el proyecto y a veces puede que necesites cerrar el Visual Studio y volver a cargar todo para que actualice

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, no entendía muy bien cual era la dinámica por la cual se agregaba el control al toolbox, voy a seguir indagando.